# Signup with google supabase

Tags: supabase

I'm trying to get the user data when the user signs up with google auth in `supabase`. The problem is that when the function `supabase.auth.signIn` is called is not giving back any data for me to update the profiles table in specific the has_accepted_privacy_policy column. Is there a way to get that data and pass it to `addAcceptedPrivacyPolicy`?

```
  const signUpWithGoogle = async() => {
    if(isPrivacyAccepted === true) {
      try {
        const { data, user, session, error } = await supabase.auth.signIn({
          provider: 'google',
        },
        {
          redirectTo: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? 'http://localhost:3000/posts' : 'https://llaalalalalla.com'
        });
        if(error) throw error;
        console.log('user ------ ', data)
        if(user) {
          addAcceptedPrivacyPolicy(user);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        notifyError(error);
      }  
    } else {
      setPrivacyAcceptedMessage(true);
    }
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't give any data back because a user isn't created until the OAuth dance has completed. What you could do instead is attach a query parameter to the `redirectTo` url to say `?accepted=true` and then update the user when the OAuth dance has completed and the user is returned to your website.

Comment: I did a verification on the url where the user is redirected